# How do I run the GCC preprocessor to get the code after macros like #define are expanded?

Tags: gcc

Is there an option that the GCC preprocessor could generate C source code and filter out irrelevant source code?

For example, a `.c` file has a `#define` switch to define for many different platforms. I'm only interested in one platform, and I want the C preprocessor to filter out unrelated code.

Does **GCC** support this?

Comment: Note that after running the preprocessor, you'll also have all `#include` s at the top of the file (so prepare for a lot of scrolling).

Comment: There is a duplicate of this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917316/gcc-preprocessor with additional answers and discussion.

Comment: Visual studio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing

Answer (score 39):

Yes. Use the `-E` option:

```
gcc -E foo.c
```

Answer (score 18):

While the `-E` option will perform all pre-processing, it also produces some very 'raw' output that might not be what you want (depending on what you want).

If you need to debug a macro expansion that's not doing what you expect, `E` is a good way to go. If you simply want to filter out the 'inactive code', but leave the remaining code in more-or-less original form, you might want to look at the answers to the following Stack Overflow question:

- *[Is there a C pre-processor which eliminates #ifdef blocks based on values defined/undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525283/is-there-a-c-pre-processor-which-eliminates-ifdef-blocks-based-on-values-defined)*

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want [unifdef](http://freshmeat.net/projects/unifdef/), not the GCC preprocessor.

Comment: moved to https://github.com/fanf2/unifdef

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake: If you are interested in running *just the preprocessor*, you can also use `cpp`:

```
cpp foo.c
```

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html for reference:

> Most often when you use the C preprocessor you do not have to invoke it explicitly: the C compiler does so automatically. However, the preprocessor is sometimes useful on its own. You can invoke the preprocessor either with the `cpp` command, or via `gcc -E`. In GCC, the preprocessor is actually integrated with the compiler rather than a separate program, and both of these commands invoke GCC and tell it to stop after the preprocessing phase.

> The `cpp` command expects two file names as arguments, *infile* and *outfile*. The preprocessor reads infile together with any other files it specifies with ‘#include’. All the output generated by the combined input files is written in *outfile*.