# Is there a tool to remove the C source code in an Undefined Macro?

Tags: linux, macros

I am reading linux kernel source code recently.

The source code use too many Macros to divide files, functions, variables.

But a lot of these Macro are ignored by me. The files, functions, variables depend on the Macro I ignore create too much disturbance.

Is there any method to remove all these files, functions, variables depend on Undefined Macros in the source project?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to remove all this... The source code contains them for a good reason (make the kernel working in all configurations). If you want to do some static analysis of the kernel consider also http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/ & http://gcc-melt.org/

Comment: You can run gcc preprocessor (`gcc -E`) to process macros.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916979/gcc-preprocessor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
make dir/file.i  - Build the form of preprocessed source code only
```

e.g.

```
make kernel/locking/spinlock.i
cat kernel/locking/spinlock.i
```

Comment: Could you describe what your answer does?

Comment: Out of pure curiosity: Do you have a source for this syntax? I have not seen it in the man page of make.

Comment: @user7427029 the feature is supported by the kernel project instead of make