# handling operations with macros in C

Tags: c, macros

I'm new to dealing with Macros and I've just stumbled into an exercise that I can't figure it out. Could someone explain to me what's happening here?
If I compile i can see what the output is but i can't get it there myself.
Thank you in advance!

```
#define M(varname, index) ( ( (unsigned char*) & varname )[index] ) 

int main(void) {
int a = 0x12345678; 
printf( "%x %x\n", M(a,0), M(a,3) );
printf( "%x %x\n", M(a,1), M(a,2) );
}
```

Comment: It is text substitution: replace the arguments where they occur in the macro definition, with the parameters passed.

Comment: Feed the program through the pre-processor `cpp` to see what the replacement is. After that, it's pointer arithmetic ...

Comment: I can explain "what's happening here" but to get better answer can you please tell us what you expected to see as output and what you actually see?

Answer (score 6):

Each Macro usage `M(x,y)` is replaced with `( (unsigned char*) & x )[y]`

So your code looks like this after preprocessing:

```
int main(void) {
    int a = 0x12345678; 
    printf( "%x %x\n", ( (unsigned char*) & a )[0], ( (unsigned char*) & a )[3] );
    printf( "%x %x\n", ( (unsigned char*) & a )[1], ( (unsigned char*) & a )[2] );
}
```

---

Like Thomas B Preusser added in the OP Question comments, most C compiler suites allow to get the pre-processed code with certain compiler flags or tools like f.e. [with GCC as mentioned here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916979/how-to-run-the-gcc-preprocessor-to-get-the-code-after-macros-like-define-are-ex)

Answer (score 3):

Macros work by replacing one thing with another before attempting to compile the code (preprocessing). So in the example you gave:

```
#define M(varname, index) ( ( (unsigned char*) & varname )[index] )
```

Each time a `M(varname, index)` occurs, it will be replaced by `( (unsigned char*) & varname )[index]`

In terms of what the code is doing, as an example (reformatted slightly for readability):

```
printf("%x %x\n", ((unsigned char*) &a)[0], ((unsigned char*) &a)[3]);
```

This:

- takes the address of variable `a`
- casts the address to an `unsigned char*`
- gets the 0th element in this pointer/array
- formats it into the string, replacing the first `%x`, as hex (`%x` is for hex)

It repeats this for the 3rd element with the second `%x`