# Processing some directives leaving others

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I use to go through **C** code having lot of `#ifdef`, `#if` and `#endif` directive which keep some portion active and some portion inactive depending on some variables are defined or not. I searched for something that can process them to generate final **C** code. But the preprocessing also does the same for `#include` and `#define`. But I want to keep them.

So, is there any thing to preprocess these files or project with some filtering?

Answer (score 2):

There are a series of programs that can do that:

- [unifdef](http://dotat.at/prog/misc/unifdef.man) - the oldest
- [sunifdef](http://sunifdef.strudl.org/) (Son of Unifdef)
- [coan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/coan2/) (Son of sunifdef)

I've used sunifdef extensively on some very contorted code and have never found it to make a mistake.  I'm ready to start using coan now, though it will still be under scrutiny for a while.  Version 4.2.2 was released today, 2010-12-20.

See also: [SO 525283](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525283/is-there-a-c-pre-processor-which-eliminates-ifdef-blocks-based-on-values-defined)

Comment: Your link to coan points to the wrong project, should be http://coan2.sourceforge.net/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/coan2/

Comment: @Hatsurkan: Oops - that was careless - thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

*I assume you're using gcc.*

If you mean all `#include`s, I think you need to remove them, expand the resulting file with `gcc -E` then add the `#includes`s back.

If you mean only the standard headers, the option `-nostdinc` may help you do what you want

```
user@host:~/test/tmp$ cat 4437465.c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef OUTPUT_TYPE
#define OUTPUT_TYPE 1
#endif

int main(void) {
#if OUTPUT_TYPE == 1
  printf("output type 1\n");
#elif OUTPUT_TYPE == 2
  printf("output type 2\n");
#else
  printf("default output type\n");
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

```
user@host:~/test/tmp$ gcc -DOUTPUT_TYPE=2 -nostdinc -E 4437465.c
# 1 "4437465.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "4437465.c"
4437465.c:1:19: error: no include path in which to search for stdio.h






int main(void) {



  printf("output type 2\n");



  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want might be actually a bad idea, as there might be definitions coming from included files, describing your architecture, for example... But any modern IDE can visualize the #if preprocessor directives.

Comment: This was my initial thought too. But you could process the included files too and scan them for defines.

Answer (score 0):

We used a custom parser to achieve what you intend to do. [Lex & YACC](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/)
 would be a good start for such tool.

On a side note, it was a really painful way to manage different versions of binaries in a large code base. If it's possible, try to isolate your optionnal code parts in different libraries that can or cannot be included in your final deliverable as a dynamic or static library.

Comment: If you can share that custom parser it will be great !