# Multiline delete with sed

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use sed to delete all occurrences of

```
#ifdef _WIN32

#endif
```

Where all that exists between #ifdef and #endif is an empty line. I have limited experience using sed, I've read some documentation on the multi line features but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it have to be sed? Would perl be OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this job, I'd recommend using a tool designed for the job - rather than `sed`.

- Use [**coan**](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/); it has a mode for editing `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` and `#if` and `#elsif` lines selectively.  For example, you'd use:

  ```
  coan source -U_WIN32 sourcefile.c
  ```

This would deal with all `_WIN32` sections, leaving behind only what was necessary.

See also my related question: [Is there a C pre-processor which eliminates #ifdef blocks based on values defined/undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525283/is-there-a-c-pre-processor-which-eliminates-ifdef-blocks-based-on-values-defined)

Comment: Thanks for contributing this one.  I knew such a program existed when I gave the `sed` answer but I didn't find it with quick googling.

Answer (score 5):

You can try `sed -e '/^#ifdef _WIN32/,/^#endif/d'` but it does not generalize to more complex cases of nesting.

Comment: where i can find the documentation for this /,/ ?

Comment: @Guilherme you can see it in the manual page where it talks about *addresses*.  Any two addresses can be joined by a comma to make an inclusive range.  E.g. `1,$` for the whole file, or `/hello/,$` for a line containing `hello` until the end of the file, or `1,10` for the first 10 lines.

Answer (score 2):

If there exists pairs of `#ifdef _WIN32/#endif` that have non-empty lines between them that you *don't* want to delete, then use the following:

```
sed 'N;N;s/\n#ifdef _WIN32\n[[:space:]]*\n#endif\n/\n/;P;D'
```

#### Input

```
this is the first line
#ifdef _WIN32
  // Don't delete this comment!
#endif

stuff here
more stuff here
#ifdef _WIN32

#endif
last line
```

#### Output

```
$ sed 'N;N;s/\n#ifdef _WIN32\n[[:space:]]*\n#endif\n/\n/;P;D' ifdef.sed
this is the first line
#ifdef _WIN32
  // Don't delete this comment!
#endif

stuff here
more stuff here
last line
```