# How to pre-compile a C source file without expand the included header file?

Tags: c, header, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am working on a large project using **C** language, which has a lot of preprocessor macros: #ifdef/#if. The macros are defined in makefile.

In order to get the clean code, I modified the makefile to use "gcc -E". But the gcc preprocessor would expand the included header file as well, which I do not expect.

Is there any method to get rid of the #ifdef/#if without expand the included header files? I searched GCC options but not find an answer yet.

An example:

```
    #include "a.h"
    #ifdef ABC
    func()
    #else
    func(a)
    #endif
    {
    ...
    }
```

In makefile, this source is compiled with -DABC, I am looking for a method to change the file to:

```
    #include "a.h"
    func()
    {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: 1. I don't see how this is useful. 2. If you *really* need this, then Dhy don't you just make a separate header file with the defines, without any header inclusion, then include this auxiliary header in the other one?

Comment: I think the point `large project` makes it difficult

Comment: Yes, this project has too many files to do this kind of change.

Comment: you could put `#ifndef _OMIT_HEADERS_`,`#endif` around the included header files, and then use `gcc -E -D_OMIT_HEADERS_`?

Comment: The initial purpose of this is to collect some source code metrics of the project, like the cyclomatic complexity. The calculation tools like CCCC can not recognize the preprocess macros.

Comment: Why can't you use this metric calculator on the `gcc -E` output with all the headers expanded?

Comment: See [Is there a C pre-processor which eliminates `#ifdef` blocks based on values defined/undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525283/is-there-a-c-pre-processor-which-eliminates-ifdef-blocks-based-on-values-define).

Comment: Thanks! The unifdef is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to remove preprocessor conditionals from your code you can use `unifdef` :

```
unifdef -DFOO header.h
```

Comment: I tried sunifdef and it works fine. Well, the code can become much cleaner. Thank you!