# How to apply single header file to the rest of the C project so it's no longer needed?

Tags: c, linux, windows, gcc, header-files

I have a C project with many header files, but I do not want to deliver to the client one specific header file with bunch of defines. I want all other files to be preprocessed with just that specific header file, and I want to regenerate all sources to a new directory, so that client is able to compile this project's new source although he wouldn't have the mentioned header file.

Is there a Linux or Windows way to do this without manual search/replace in editor?

Comment: I suppose you can cripple the other #includes like `#inc lude` and then run the C preprocessor on the files (gcc -E or so).  This could get pretty ugly though--why not just give your client the file?

Comment: I would use a tool like `m4` - convert the special header to a bunch of m4 macros and then apply this to all the source files.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Please write your reply as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @avra: Consider it done!

Comment: You might find the answers to [Is there a C prep-processor which eliminates `#ifdef` blocks based on values defined/undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525283/is-there-a-c-pre-processor-which-eliminates-ifdef-blocks-based-on-values-define) useful.  Either `sunifdef` or `coan` would probably help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a macro processing tool such as [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/), which is widely available (it's standard on most Linux and *nix distributions, as it's used by autoconf, sendmail, *et al*). Convert the special header to a bunch of `m4` macros and then apply this to all the source files.

Note that there are plenty of other alternatives to `m4`, and scripting languages such as Perl could also be considered.