# Tool to remove/Apply ifdef's/else's from codebase

Tags: c, preprocessor-directive

I have a pretty big codebase and I wanted to clean it out by removing and applying some ifdef's scattered around it. For example, I have lot's of these:

**test.c**

```
#ifdef MYCHECK
    // do other sutff
#else
    // do stuff
#endif
```

Is there a tool that allows me to run through the entire codebase and remove all that code, leaving only the code inside my variable condition? For example:

```
nicetool -D MYCHECK *.c
```

Would result in:

**test.c**

```
// do other stuff
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a C pre-processor which eliminates #ifdef blocks based on values defined/undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525283/is-there-a-c-pre-processor-which-eliminates-ifdef-blocks-based-on-values-define)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like [unifdef](http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/)  is what you want, it is also used in the [Linux kernel](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/headers_install.sh). This is the description of the tool from the linked site (*emphasis mine*):

> **The unifdef utility selectively processes conditional C preprocessor #if and #ifdef directives**. It removes from a file both the directives and the additional text that they delimit, while otherwise leaving the file alone.
>
> It is useful for avoiding distractions when studying code that uses #ifdef heavily for portability: my original motivation was to understand xterm's pty handling code. It can be used as a lightweight preprocessor; **for example the Linux kernel uses unifdef to strip out #ifdef **KERNEL** sections from the headers it exports to userland**. You can use unifdef with languages other than C; for example UIT, a publisher in Cambridge where I live, uses unifdef with LaTeX.

If you check out the [manual](http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/unifdef.txt) there are some exceptions listed in the BUGS section:

> Handling one line at a time means preprocessor directives split across
> more than one physical line (because of comments or backslash-newline) cannot be handled in every situation.
>
> Trigraphs are not recognized.
>
> There is no support for macros with different definitions at different
> points in the source file.
>
> The text-mode and ignore functionality does not correspond to modern
> cpp(1) behaviour.

Other options include [Sunifdef](http://freecode.com/projects/sunifdef) whose main site no longer is available and has not been updated since 2008 and [Coan: The C Preprocessor Chainsaw](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/) which describes itself as:

> Coan is a software engineering tool for analysing preprocessor-based configurations of C or C++ source code. Its principal use is to simplify a body of source code by eliminating any parts that are redundant with respect to a specified configuration. Dead code removal is an application of this sort.
>
> Coan is most useful to developers of constantly evolving products with large code bases, where preprocessor definitions and #if-directives are used differentiate progressive releases or parallel variants of the product. In these settings the upkeep of the product's configuration tree can become difficult and the incidence of configuration-related defects can become costly.

Comment: See the proposed duplicate question; `sunifdef` (Son of `unifdef`) and [`coan`](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/) are also options.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler interesting, it does not look like `sunifdef` is being maintained anymore but `coan` does look interesting.

Comment: Coan is supposed to replace sunifdef.  I've used sunifdef for a number of years with no problems (on some extremely contorted rats nests of `#ifdef` code) with no problems.  Coan was a bit more of a work in progress, so I didn't use it — but it was several years ago that I last did any work with Coan so it has probably improved since then.