# How can I remove all #if 0 from code?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a large code I want to go over and it has a lot of parts "macroed out":

```
#define DEBUG 0
#if DEBUG
...
#endif
```

The (...) is mostly *debug printf's*. Is there a way to remove all these code lines that eventually won't execute?

Comment: By using preprocessor of your C compiler or by writing a small utility to do so and using it?

Comment: @MikeCAT I guess I could write a python script to fix my code, but is there a built-in tool for that?

Comment: I suggest commenting out all includes (so as not to expand them) and then asking your compiler for preprocessor-output. Look in the manual for the proper option. There might be a problem with all the #define's and #undefine's being stripped out, if they were meant to influence the included contents though, or later conditionals defend on macros defined in them.

Comment: I know this is a comment which does'n answer your question: I wouldn't call this "macroed out". You may need the _debug prints_ already in the next step of your development cycle.

Comment: @user3078414 the debug prints are very needed, but not when I want to read the base code in order to understand it...

Comment: Taking a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738929/tool-to-remove-apply-ifdefs-elses-from-codebase) may help.

Comment: There's a partial C preprocessor https://github.com/BR903/cppp It only works with `#iffdef`, not `#if` but this is solvable with a bit of `sed`.

Comment: I think it is best to go through them one by one - to prevent you having unintended consequences

Comment: Can you use a folding editor for reading? Many editors off little "[-]" on the left window border, clicking it will hide typical code constructs and leave a "[+]", to be clicked for unhiding the code part.