# Compute minimal list of macro combinations from source

Tags: c-preprocessor

How would one compute efficiently the minimal list of macro definitions combinations that will give the same code ? The list of macros is known before-hand.

The objective would be to compile less versions of the program (possibly a shader) and thus skip some compilation time by knowing what macro combinations are equivalent.
eg. if a program built with MACRO_A and MACRO_B is the same as a program built only with MACRO_A.

For the sake of simplicity, those macro are either defined or not, and their value doesn't matter (meaning there is no #if SOMEMACRO).

For example with:

```
#ifdef A
  #ifdef B
    // some code
  #endif
  // some code
#elif defined(C)
 // some code
#else
  // some code
#endif
```

A trivial way to generate all the programs would be to compile with all the combinations made from A,B and C. It would mean creating 2^3=8 combinations. However, only the following combinations really are useful (`!` means the macro is not defined, `~`that the macro doesn't matter and can be either defined or undefined ):

- `( A,  B, ~C)` (same as A, B, C and A, B, !C)
- `( A, !B, ~C)`
- `(!A, ~B,  C)`
- `(!A, ~B, !C)`

Which means compiling only programs with the following definitions is enough:

- A B
- A
- C
- No defines

With this list, I know that when asked for a program with the `(A, !B, C)` combination I can simply use the one built with only A defined.

What tools could be used ?

Notes:

- Most preprocessors will only give the path for a given set of defines
- Perhaps building the control flow graph of the preprocessor would help?
- Some work has been done with clang [here](http://www.llvm.org/devmtg/2016-11/Slides/Trull-ExtendingClangASTMatchers.pdf) by J. Trull to add conditional nodes to the AST, but seems to be aimed at refactoring, not sure if it is the best way to do it

Comment: This is loosely related to (but not a duplicate of) [Is there a C pre-processor which eliminates `#ifdef` blocks based on values defined or undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525283/) and the Coan (Coan2) tool mentioned there may be helpful.  However, I'm not sure that it can address your full requirement.  It may help, though.

Comment: Part of the process seems a logical optimisation, to find an efficient way of configuring each possible resulting code, but only once. I.e. find the combinations which are NOT needed anymore after having used a logically identical one already. For this part I want to mention the method based on Karnaugh Veitch diagrams: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map Determining which combination has which resulting code and identifying the combinations which result in identical code is the first step.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks I edited the post

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sadly those tools only eliminate dead code, which is useful when you want to fully remove use of a deprecated macro, but this is not the case here. Doing so seems (to me) way easier because it is closer to a normal preprocessor job

Comment: @Yunnosch Indeed the logical optimisation is the second step, Karnaugh's maps could be a solution. I'm more interested in the 'identifying the combinations' which is the hardest part IMO though.