# Recursively remove preprocessor macros

Tags: c++, c, building

I have a source tree for a program I am working on which is written in mixed C/C++ code. For debugging purposes, I would like to be able to run a command line tool like `unifdef` on the entire tree (recursively) to remove a certain set of `#ifdef/#endif` macros from all source files.

I was wondering if there was any specific way I could go about doing this in an efficient way. Any help would be appriciated, thank you.

Comment: You need to do this in C or C++, or you need to write a shell script that does this?

Comment: Use the `find` command with the `-exec` option to execute a command on all the files in a souce tree.

Comment: There is no "mixed C/C++ code". A single source file can only be either C or C++. A c++ compiler cannot compile C code.

Comment: @Olaf I think he means that he has both C and C++ source files in his project.

Comment: Unclear. The code inside an `#ifdef` directive will be compiled if the symbol is defined. Why can't you just define (or undefine) the symbol from makefile/build script ?

Comment: @Barmar: Who knows? There are a lot of people thinking C coding style **is** C.

Comment: @Olaf "A c++ compiler cannot compile C code." Eh??? Did you mean the other  way around?

Comment: @DYZ: No. They are different languages! Read the standards. **Identical syntax/grammar does not imply identical semantics**. Read my comments **carefully** again!

Comment: @Olaf Surely I can compile almost any C code with a C++ compiler. There are C statements that have different semantics from their C++ lookalikes, but your statement is too strong to be true.

Comment: They have a nearly identical preprocessor. I have both C and C++ source files which share macros. Of course you cannot compile C++ with a C compiler (although generally the reverse does work properly). I'm not trying to compile anything, just remove unused macros.

Comment: @DYZ: Try these simple definitions: `static const int i = 10; static int a[i] = { 0 };`.  You also want to learn about name-mangling. Why do you think one has to use `extern "C"` in C++ for C function declarations? Just learn both languages well enough. As you seem not to have understood what I wrote: If you use C coding style in C++ does not make your program C compatible!

Comment: @Olaf I have multiple source files. There are some files with C++ code and some files which contain C code. In reality, it doesn't even matter because I'm talking about the C preprocessor, not the code itself. (Additionally, the only reason you have to `extern "C"` in C++ is because of symbol mangling, both are still compiled to assembly in effectively the same manner.

Comment: @DYZ: Better than you do apparently! Note that the two definitions above compile fine in C++, although each one itself is valid for both languages. THe semantics make the difference.

Comment: It seems that you want to remove some `#ifdef`s and the corresponding `#endif` statement, so that the code between the directives now compiles unconditionally. How are you going to treat `#else`s and `#ifndef`s?

Comment: @M Oehm Not exactly—I want to remove the code between them if it will not be compiled normally and leave the code if it will be compiled normally. I basically just want to evaluate the blocks as the preprocessor would. I want to be able to provide the macros that I want to be defined and then the changes would be computed.

Comment: @beeselmane Most compilers have an option to save the output of the preprocessor in a file. So compile your code with that option.

Comment: See also [Is there a C pre-processor which eliminates `#ifdef` blocks based on values defined/undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525283/is-there-a-c-pre-processor-which-eliminates-ifdef-blocks-based-on-values-define).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue by using the following command:

`find . -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.hpp' -exec unifdef <macro definitions> -o '{} {} ;'`