# How to compare two files ignoring code inside #ifdef?

Tags: c, version-control, diff, conditional-compilation

Suppose we have and original source file which includes code blocks inside #ifdef conditionals and another file which has been manually "preprocessed", so some of the code blocks have been included an others have been removed. How can I  see only modifications that don't come from an `#ifdef`?

As an example, the original file could be:

```
#ifdef X
  blabla1
#else
  blabla2
#endif
```

and the modified file is:

```
blabla2
new line
```

I only want to detect that `new line` has been added.

Is there a tool or a short way to do this? If I knew in advance if `X` was defined or not, I could strip the irrelevant code with `unifdef`, but in this case I don't know it and once there are many variables, trying all possible combinations is infeasible.

I think a way to do it would be through a `diff` to identify the differences and then check if the differences are inside an ifdef, but this doesn't seem straightforward to implement.

Comment: You can pre-process the file(s) and then compare the pre-processed output.

Comment: Note that your manually pre-processed, modified file _must_ have assumed certain defines, otherwise it cannot achieve its resulting C file.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Correct, I just don't know them.

Comment: See [Is there a preprocessor which eliminates `#ifdef` blocks based on values defined/undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525283) for tools (Son of Ifdef, Coan) that can do the 'manual preprocessing' automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `gcc -E` which expands all preprocessor input. So if you wanted to try expanding some files which have `#ifdef X` and `#ifdef Y` you can use:
`gcc -E -DX -DY [filename] | clang-format`.

`clang-format` should also get rid of empty lines for you.

You can also try using `unifdef` instead of `gcc -E` and you can look up the man page for what options you need there.