# unifdef with inequality based constraints

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Given the following C source code

```
#ifdef FOO
int bar = 1;
#endif
#if FOO == 0
int x = 0;
#elif FOO == 1
int x = 1;
#elif FOO == 2
int x = 2;
#endif
```

I can preprocess the source code (e.g. with [unifdef / coan](https://stackoverflow.com/q/525283/73299)) as if `FOO` was either undefined, defined at all or defined as a specific value (`coan -DFOO=1 ...` would rewrite the code as `int bar = 1; int x = 1;`).

However, for some variables I want to preprocess on (e.g. `_MSC_VER`) I don't know the exact value, but I know which values I want to filter out.
Ideally, I could run `coan -DFOO!=0` or `coan -DFOO>0` to drop the parts that don't match but keep the `#if`s that can't be evaluated yet.

Is there any preprocessor that can handle more advanced constraints like this?

Comment: Your definition of `x` could just be `int x = FOO;`.

Comment: Also, you say that you "don't know the exact value [of `_MSC_VER`], but I know which values I want to filter out". That doesn't really make any sense to me. If you don't know the possible values, how can you know what values you want to "filter out"?

Comment: There's also `sunifdef` (Son of `unifdef`), but that's intermediate between `unifdef` and `coan` in functionality.  I suspect that if `coan` can't do it, there isn't (yet) a tool that does it.  I take it that you've decided to stop supporting some antiquated versions of `_MSC_VER` and want to remove the code that depends on versions older than some threshold value.  Actually doing that would be hard — and that might be being polite about it if you have code with `#if _MSC_VER >= 3210` or `#if _MSC_VER < 5432` or other more complex constructs.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Let's assume I there are `#ifdef`s for `FOO==0` to `FOO==4` and I want to either remove everything for `FOO=0` _and_ `FOO=1` or keep everything for `FOO=3` and `FOO=4`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler coan already has three states - 'matches' (=remove conditional, keep code), 'doesn't match' (=remove everything) and 'unknown' (=keep everything), so the more complex constructs could be left as they are